# C# Generic Inheritance Issue with Base Library

Tags: c#, generics, inheritance

Given the following classes/interfaces defined in a base library:

```
public interface IWorkContext {
    T Node<T>() where T : class, IHierachy<T>;
    IHierachyItem Node();
}

public interface IHierachyItem {
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; }
}

public interface IHierachy<T> : IHierachyItem where T : IHierachy<T> {
    T Parent { get; set; }
    IList<T> Children { get; set; }
}

public class WorkContext {
    public static IWorkContext Current {
        get { return DependencyResolver.Current.GetService<IWorkContext>(); }
    }
}
```

Which has the following implentation inside another library (that references the base library above):

```
public class DefaultWorkContext : IWorkContext {
    // Nhibernate session
    private readonly ISession _session;

    public DefaultWorkContext(ISession session) {
        _session = session;
    }

    public T Node<T>() where T : class, IHierachy<T> {
        return _session.Get<T>(2);
    }

    public IHierachyItem Node() {
        return Node<SiteMapNode>();
    }
}
```

Where SiteMapNode exists in the same library (and is mapped to a database table):

```
public class SiteMapNode : IHierachy<SiteMapNode> {
    public virtual int Id { get; set; }
    public virtual SiteMapNode Parent { get; set; }
    public virtual string Title { get; set; }
    public virtual IList<SiteMapNode> Children { get; set; }

    public SiteMapNode() {
        Children = new List<SiteMapNode>();
    }
}
```

I can say the following to access a node and get the parent:

```
var node = WorkContext.Current.Node();
var parentNode = ((IHierachy<SiteMapNode>)node).Parent;

var node2 = WorkContext.Current.Node<SiteMapNode>();
var parentNode2 = node2.Parent;
```

However i don't like either approach as option 1 requires a case and option 2 requires me to pass a default type.

Is it possible to refactor this sample so that i can access the Parent and Child the same way I get the Id and Title.

I hope i've explained the problem clear enough. I'd appreciate the help. Thanks

Comment: Generally, the simplest example that exhibits the condition you want to ask about is better...

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Your problem might be more clear if you used explicit types instead of `var`.  Declaring a variable with `var` does not make the variable type dynamic, it just makes the compiler figure out what specific type the variable needs to be (and it can be dangerous because you don't know as clearly what type it determines).

So, having declared variables with a specific type (whether you know what that type is or not), you can then only access what that declared type knows unless you cast it appropriately.

I think in the end there is no way to accomplish exactly what you want without specifying a type at some point as a type argument (in angle-brackets) or an explicit cast.  You apparently want to convert a non-specific iherited/implementing type to a handy specific type, but that requires telling the complier a specific type for it to become.

But you may get closer to what you'd like by changing your approach.  What if you used a non-generic `IHierarchy`?  (also correct the spelling)  If...

```
public inetrface IHierarchy : IHierarchyItem
{
    IHierarchy Parent { get; set; }
    IList<IHierarchy> Children { get; set; }
}
```

...then any `IHierarchy node` variable could access `node.Parent` and `node.Children`... and also `node.Id` and `node.Title` because the `IHierarchyItem` is required and thus is known to `IHierarchy`.

This approach would handle the hierarchy aspects easily and allows polymorphism in your `WorkContext.Current` (etc) return values, but it would require explicit casting from there to access anything specific to a class outside of the defined members of `IHierarchy`.  It's not clear how much of an issue that might be for your purpose.

You could also perhaps layer a generic `IHierarchy<T> : IHierarchy` on top of it to allow handling by a specific type without further casting.  You might have to define one or both interface members explicitly rather than implicitly (in implementing classes) to avoid name collisions on the properties without generic type arguments.

**EDITED TO ADD:**

For example, something like:

```
public interface IHierarchy<T> : IHierarchy // Implies IHierarchyItem
    where T : IHierarchy<T>
{ ... } // As you had it.
```

Then in your implementation class:

```
public SiteMapNode : IHierarchy<SiteMapNode> // Implies IHierarchy
{
    private SiteMapNode _Parent;
    private IList<SiteMapNode> _Children;

    // Implicit implement of IHierarchyItem and members of SiteMapNode itself.
    int Id { get; set; }
    string Title { get; set; } 

    // Implicit implementation of IHierarchy<SiteMapNode> members
    // These are also members of SiteMapNode itself.

    SiteMapNode Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; }
        set { _Parent = value; }
    }

    IList<SiteMapNode> Children
    {
        get return _Children;
        set _Children = value;
    }

    // Explicit implementation of IHierarchy members
    // The interface prefix is required to distinguish these from the
    // type-specific members above to declare different return types.

    IHierarchy IHierarchy.Parent
    {
        get { return _Parent; } // Might need (IHierarchy) cast
        set { Parent = (SiteMapNode)value; }
    }

    IList<IHierarchy> IHierarchy.Children
    {
        get { return _Children; } // Might need (IList<IHierarchy>) cast
        set { _Children = (IList<SiteMapNode>)value; }
    }
}
```

(Or get fancier and have more sanity-checking in the IHierarchy implementations.)  I might have missed some other explicit casting needed also; I'm not positive that the lists can be cast directly in this way, but I think by having IHierarchy<T> inherit IHierarchy it ensures that SiteMapNode is a valid IHierarchy and thus the elements of the list work for both list types).  If that list casting doesn't work, you may have to create a custom  generic collection class to manage the children as both unspecified IHierarchy and as generic IHierarchy<T>.

For performance reasons you may want to add `IHierarchy _CastParent;` and `IList<IHierarchy> _CastChildren;` members and save the unspecified IHierarchy casts of these objects to avoid having to repeatedly recast them.  I suggest that you always cast to the specific types (when setting from the unspecified) but you might defer casting from the specific types to the unspecified references until they are actually needed.

Now, all that, of course, is only if this extra complexity is actually helpful for what you need.  It would allow you to handle the hierarchy objects as unspecified types (which might be cast more specific later, or never) or as specific or generic hierarchy types which would preserve their type knowledge for handling without casting.  You would still need to cast to a specific type at some point to convert from an unspecified IHierarchy return type if you wanted to then handle them as the type-specific hierarchy.

Comment: Thanks but I'm not quite sure I follow you at the end. I've just tried adding a generic interface on top of an non generic IHierachy interface but I can't get it to work. I'd appreciate it if you could add some more detail. Thanks

Comment: Okay @nfplee, I've added an example of what I had mentioned at the end.  For more info, try searching for: C# explicit interface implementation.

Comment: Lol done, I don't fully get the points system on this site tbh. I thought marking it as the answer was enough.

Comment: Thanks, @nfplee.  The actual asker (only) can select the one "accepted" answer to their question.  Anyone with enough reputation points can upvote on any answer (except one of their own, I guess?).  So, some people can accept an answer but can't yet upvote, some can do both, and many others can upvote an answer but weren't the asker of the question.  At a higher level you can downvote--an even bigger responsibility, typically to negate bogus answers--which is not the really same as undoing an upvote (they are separate toggles).